# How to reverse DOM changes by clicking outside of search input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I click into the search input, it works as desired.

But when I click into the search input again, it reverses the effect of the first click.

It should reverse the effect of the first click when I click outside the search input.

Here is my code:

```js
function active() {
  let body = document.body;
  let inp = document.getElementById("inpt")
  body.classList.toggle("bg")
  inp.classList.toggle("iwidth")
}
```

```css
input {
  outline: none;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.iwidth {
  width: 300px;
}

.bg {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  transition: 300ms;
}
```

```html
<input type="search" name="" id="inpt" onclick="active()">
```

Comment: java != javascript

Comment: It won't work, because you only handle the click event on your input element. You will need a new eventlistener for outside click.

Comment: @cs.matyi You are right! But i don't know how to do that. I don't have much knowledge of javascript.

Comment: I think instead of `onClick`, change it to `onfocus`. It should work

Comment: There is no real need to handle a "click outside" here - clicking the inout gave it _focus_, so you can subscribe to its own `blur` event here for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `toggle()`, use `add()` and `remove()` so that when you click on the `input` element twice, the focus doesn't go off

Add this to your `js` code. If you clicked on any element which is not the `input` element, the classes are removed and it goes back to normal

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target.id != "inpt") {
        inactive();
    }
})
```

---

Whole code:

```js
function active() {
  let body = document.body;
  let inp = document.getElementById("inpt")
  body.classList.add("bg")
  inp.classList.add("iwidth")
}

function inactive() {
  let body = document.body;
  let inp = document.getElementById("inpt")
  body.classList.remove("bg")
  inp.classList.remove("iwidth")
}

document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.id != "inpt") {
    inactive();
  }
})
```

```css
input {
  outline: none;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.iwidth {
  width: 300px;
}

.bg {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  transition: 300ms;
}
```

```html
<input type="search" name="" id="inpt" onclick="active()">
```

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is:

```
<input type="search" name="" id="inpt" onfocus="active()" onblur="deactivate()">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use onfocus and on blur

```js
function active() {
            let body = document.body;
            let inp = document.getElementById("inpt")
            body.classList.toggle("bg")
            inp.classList.toggle("iwidth")
        }
```

```css
input {
    outline: none;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 2px;
}
.iwidth {
    width: 300px;
}
.bg {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0,0.8);
    transition: 300ms;
}
```

```html
<input type="search" name="" id="inpt" onfocus="active()" onblur="alert('deactivate')">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="search" name="" id="inpt" onblur="blurF()" onfocus="focusF()">

// Lose focus  
function blurF() {
  let body = document.body;
  let inp = document.getElementById("inpt")
  body.classList.remove("bg")
  inp.classList.remove("iwidth")
}
// Get focus
function focusF() {
  let body = document.body;
  let inp = document.getElementById("inpt")
  body.classList.add("bg")
  inp.classList.add("iwidth")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you generally have two options:

1. Use only CSS-based solution
   This is more natural and even easier to implement. You need to simply use css selector with :focuse pseud class.
   Ex.

```css
input:focus{
       /* add your css here */
}
```

2. Add transformation function on releasing the control focus
   If you continue your approach you need to add a function to transform back when you go out of focus. See the example:

```html
<input type="search" name="" id="inpt" onclick="active()" onfocusout="deactivate()" />
```